# Why this algorithm for egyptian fractions doesn't terminate in ~$2$% cases?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, divisibility, egyptian-fractions

I thought up yet another algorithm for egyptian fraction expansion which turned out to be very effective (in terms of the length and the denominator size) - in most cases. However, for some fractions it doesn't terminate at all - it leads to an infinite loop.

Here is the algorithm:

---

Let $\frac{p}{q}<1$ and $p,q$ coprime. Find the minimal $m$ such that $q/(p+m)$ is an integer. We only need to consider $m \in [1,q-p]$. Represent the fraction as: $$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{p+m}{q}-\frac{m}{q}$$

Now to obtain a positive term instead of a negative one, we split the first fraction in two:
$$\frac{p+m}{q}-\frac{m}{q}=\frac{p+m}{2q}+\frac{p+m}{2q}-\frac{m}{q}=\frac{p+m}{2q}+\frac{p-m}{2q}$$

Here is a conditional: if $p<m$, then repeat the previous step (add $\frac{p+m}{4q}$ to the negative fraction). And so on, until both terms are positive. If $p>m$ then $\frac{p}{q} \to \frac{p-m}{2q}$ and we repeat the first step of the algorithm.

---

The working name is complementary method, so I will use CM to denote it for now.

Despite its simplicity (it's not at all obvious why we are dividing by $2$ instead of using some other way to expand the first term) the algorithm works very well. In a lot of cases it beats every other algorithm I tried.

Since the greedy algorithm and Engel expansion are usually bad in terms of denominator size, I used two other methods to compare: [Binary Remainder Method](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/binary.html) and my own 'Splitting-Joining method' (the details can be found in my [Mathematica SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136914/36559). I also compared it to a modification of Engel proposed by Daniel Fischer [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2131921/269624) and CM is mostly better for the examples he provided.

Some examples of the best results (a sequence of denominators is provided in each case):

`4/49: CM {14,98}; BR {16,98,196,392,784}; SJ {13,325,925,1813}`

`3/35: CM {14,70}; BR {16,70,140,560}; SJ {20,28}`

`47/104: CM {4,8,13}; BR {4,8,16,104,208}; SJ {4, 14, 26, 28, 52, 70, 104, 130, 182}`

Some examples of the worst results (but still valid - algorithm terminates):

`94/191: CM {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 24448, 48896, 97792, 195584, 391168, 782336, 1564672}`

`65/157: CM {4, 8, 32, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 10048, 20096, 40192, 80384, 160768, 643072}`

`52/139: CM {4, 16, 32, 64, 128, 278, 556, 1112, 2224, 8896, 17792}`

However, in these cases both BR and SJ methods also give long expansions with large denominators.

---

> Now the real problem which I'm trying to solve - **why in some cases the algorithm doesn't terminate, but leads to loops**? From large scale experiments I estimates the proportion of such fractions to be about $1.8$% (for numerators and denominators below $1000$).

The examples of such 'bad' fractions are:

$$\frac{41}{111},\frac{5}{87},\frac{8}{87},\frac{14}{87},\frac{47}{87},\frac{61}{102},\frac{17}{69},\frac{33}{119},\frac{38}{93},\frac{77}{177},\frac{32}{57},\frac{99}{185},\frac{98}{141},\frac{100}{129},\dots$$

The most common denominator is $87$ for some reason. Note that not all of the denominators and/or numerators are prime.

The problem can be solved by using $\frac{p-1}{q}$ instead, but not in every case, for example $7/87$ doesn't work either. However, both $6/87$ and $2/87$ work, and give different denominators, so we can expand $8/87$ after all.

I think the problem might be related to the use of the expansion $1=1/2+1/2$ to divide the fist term. However, when I tried some other schemes, I didn't get good results (for example, I've got repeating fractions when using $1=1/3+2/3$).

---

The working Mathematica code for the algorithm is:

```
x=6/87;
p0=Numerator[x];
q0=Denominator[x];
S=0;
Nm=100;
a=Table[1,{k,1,Nm}];
m=Table[1,{k,1,Nm}];
p1=p0;
q1=q0;
j=1;
While[Abs[p0]>1&&j<=Nm&&q0<10^35,M=Catch[Do[If[FractionalPart[q0/(p0+k)]<1/10^55,Throw[k]],{k,0,q0-p0}]];
m[[j]]=M;
a[[j]]=(p0+M)/(2 q0);
p1=Numerator[a[[j]]-M/q0];
q1=Denominator[a[[j]]-M/q0];
While[p1<0,a[[j]]=a[[j]]/2;
p1=Numerator[a[[j]]+p1/q1];
q1=Denominator[a[[j]]+p1/q1]];
If[a[[j]]!=1,S+=a[[j]]];
j++;
p0=p1;q0=q1];
a[[j]]=p1/q1;
S+=a[[j]];
Denominator[Table[a[[k]],{k,1,j}]]
```

---

> And the second question: how to modify the algorithm so it always terminates?

---

**Update:**

Among the first $10000$ fractions with $p \neq 1$ in lexicographic order there are $269$ fractions for which this algorithm doesn't work. (Seems to be more than $2$%). They are:

`5/33,5/51,2/55,32/55,4/57,7/57,13/57,23/57,32/57,6/65,43/66,4/69,8/69,11/69,17/69,40/69,50/69,8/85,59/85,4/87,5/87,7/87,8/87,14/87,34/87,47/87,62/87,65/87,76/87,5/93,7/93,10/93,19/93,38/93,50/93,67/93,6/95,8/95,63/95,61/102,9/110,59/110,4/111,7/111,8/111,13/111,16/111,22/111,25/111,31/111,41/111,44/111,59/111,62/111,68/111,82/111,7/114,65/114,71/114,83/114,103/114,6/115,11/115,17/115,63/115,3/119,5/119,10/119,15/119,16/119,33/119,37/119,45/119,61/119,66/119,67/119,71/119,73/119,78/119,96/119,101/119,4/123,5/123,8/123,10/123,11/123,17/123,20/123,26/123,29/123,35/123,46/123,49/123,67/123,70/123,76/123,86/123,92/123,4/129,5/129,10/129,13/129,14/129,19/129,28/129,31/129,37/129,47/129,53/129,71/129,74/129,80/129,91/129,100/129,77/130,53/132,119/132,11/138,31/138,77/138,85/138,91/138,103/138,4/141,5/141,7/141,8/141,14/141,16/141,17/141,23/141,32/141,35/141,41/141,52/141,55/141,74/141,79/141,82/141,88/141,98/141,101/141,110/141,121/141,3/143,7/143,21/143,40/143,42/143,60/143,73/143,80/143,98/143,120/143,138/143,6/145,8/145,13/145,21/145,64/145,79/145,93/145,122/145,6/155,7/155,9/155,12/155,14/155,69/155,99/155,102/155,107/155,131/155,5/159,7/159,10/159,11/159,14/159,19/159,20/159,23/159,32/159,38/159,58/159,64/159,83/159,85/159,91/159,113/159,116/159,125/159,136/159,9/161,11/161,101/161,103/161,16/165,41/165,61/165,116/165,151/165,33/170,101/170,7/174,37/174,43/174,65/174,95/174,97/174,101/174,103/174,115/174,155/174,8/175,11/175,78/175,108/175,111/175,113/175,116/175,148/175,4/177,5/177,8/177,10/177,11/177,13/177,17/177,19/177,20/177,22/177,26/177,29/177,35/177,38/177,44/177,64/177,67/177,70/177,77/177,94/177,95/177,97/177,103/177,122/177,128/177,131/177,137/177,140/177,154/177,4/183,5/183,7/183,10/183,11/183,13/183,14/183,19/183,20/183,22/183,28/183,34/183,37/183,40/183,49/183,65/183,68/183,71/183,74/183`

---

**Update 2 (Important)**

> The question was deleted for a time, because for some of the listed fraction algorithm seems to work just fine if it's done by hand. There is some error in my code, which I hadn't been able to find yet.
>
> But there are fractions which lead to loops by hand as well (such as $41/111$) so the question still stands.

Comment: This could be entirely meaningless, but I notice that every entry of https://oeis.org/A273199 (up to $183$) appears as a denominator in your list of $269$ "bad" fractions.  (I found the entry by searching on $57,69,87,93$, which are the first few denominators in your list that appear with many numerators.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's still an error in your code, in the `While` loop you take if $p<m$:

```
While[p1<0,a[[j]]=a[[j]]/2;
p1=Numerator[a[[j]]+p1/q1];
q1=Denominator[a[[j]]+p1/q1]];
```

The problem is that after you update `p1`, the calculation `q1 = Denominator[a[[j]] + p1/q1]` is done with the old value of `q1` but the *new* value of `p1`. A quick fix: change the loop to

```
While[p1<0,a[[j]]=a[[j]]/2;
{p1,q1}={Numerator[a[[j]]+p1/q1], Denominator[a[[j]]+p1/q1]}];
```

Here's my own implementation of this algorithm, in convenient function-call form: just run `egyptian[41/111]` to get back `{1/4,1/12,1/48,1/74,1/592}`. I've tested  it on all fractions with denominator less than $200$, and it works correctly:

```
split[Rational[p_,q_]]:=Module[{m, t=1},
  m=First@Select[Range[q-p],IntegerQ[q/(p+#)]&,1];
  While[(2^t-1)p < m,t++];
  Return[{(p+m)/(2^t q),((2^t-1)p-m)/(2^t q)}];
];

egyptian[fraction_Rational]:=Module[{first,rest},
  If[Numerator[fraction]==1,Return[{fraction}]];
  {first,rest} = split[fraction];
  Return[Prepend[first] @ egyptian[rest]];
];
```

(Here, `split` is a helper function that returns the two parts of the representation of $\frac pq$ as $\frac{p+m}{2q} + \frac{p-m}{2q}$ or as $\frac{p+m}{4q} + \frac{3p-m}{4q}$ or in general as $\frac{p+m}{2^t q} + \frac{(2^t-1)p-m}{2^t q}$ for whichever $t$ is the first to work. Then `egyptian` just repeatedly applies this to get the Egyptian fraction we wanted.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to check the fractions I had a problem with by hand (don't remember where I put my notes on this), and thank you very much for finding the mistake in my algorithm! Going to test your corrections on a larger number of fractions, there is likely an improvement even in cases which worked before